# Get unlocked resources azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-resource-group

I need a powershell script to get a list of all unlocked resource groups.
If you run Get-AzureRmResourceLock it will show the resources that are currently locked not the ones that are unlocked

Comment: Do you want to check if specific resources have locks or resource groups?

Comment: @anabell Have you had a chance to check the answer below? Does that help?

Comment: I want to check if resource groups have locks

Comment: @anabell Please check the provided answer below. Elaborate your requirement if that isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can go about doing this is as follows:

1. Get all Resource Groups in your Subscription

```
$AllRGs = $(Get-AzResourceGroup | Select-Object ResourceGroupName).ResourceGroupName
```

2. Get the Resource Groups that have locks

```
$lockedRGs = $(Get-AzResourceLock | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Authorization/locks"} | Select-Object ResourceGroupName).ResourceGroupName
```

3. Take a diff of the two

```
$noLockRGs = $AllRGs | Where-Object {$lockedRGs -notcontains $_}
```